# Python Django 3.1 The included URLconf 'mysite.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm currently learning django by tutorial.
So I changed my return-renders to class-generic in views.
in URLs I added as_view() and then it gave me an error.

my traceback:

```
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'mysite.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patter
ns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:id>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:id>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from .models import Question
from django.template import loader
from django.views import generic

class IndexView(generic.listView):
   template_name = 'myapp/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
   def get_queryset(self):
       return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
   model = Question
   template_name = 'myapp/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
   model = Question
   template_name = 'myapp/results.html'


def vote(request, question_id):
   question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=question_id)
   try:
       selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(id=request.POST['choice'])
   except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
       return render(request, 'myapp/detail.html',
                     {'question': question,
                      'error_message': "You didn't select a choice."}
                     )
   else:
       selected_choice.votes += 1
       selected_choice.save()
       return HttpResponseResponse(reverse_lazy('myapp:results', args=(question_id,)))
```

I considered other tutorials and threads but found nothing about my subject. I think I missed something about IDs and PKs.

Comment: By default, you should use `<int:pk>` instead of `<int:id>` in the paths for class based views. However, I don't think that explains your error. Please show your project's urls.py (the one in the same directory as `settings.py`).

Comment: There's my urls.py from the project's folder
`
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
`

Comment: The error message isn't very useful for you here, because it doesn't tell you why Django couldn't load the URLs. I would run `python manage.py shell`, and then `import myapp.views`, which should give you a more informative error message.

Comment: Huge thanks! 
It told me that there's no listView in views.generic module.
So I kinda mistyped. It should be "class IndexView(generic.ListView):" in views.py

Comment: Can you show your `models.py` file?

Answer (score 0):

`class IndexView(generic.listView):` please change it to `class IndexView(generic.ListView):`. Here you use `listView` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message just bcoz of error in code. I didnt specify the class name when imported the models page
from . models import classname
is the right where this class is used in that page
from . models import
is wrong

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).